# Virtual KVM with Logitech Unify Technology

Tags: windows-10, kvm-switch, macos-catalina, logitech-unifying-receiver

I want to use my Logitech MX Keys "Easy-Switch" Keys as a virtual KVM.

My Setup has following devices:

Logitech MX Keys (Keyboard)

Logitech MX Master (Mouse)

MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016)

Dell Latitude 5300 2 in 1 (Windows Laptop)

DELL WD19 (Dock) - connected with Windows Laptop

2x U28R550UQU

- MacBook: both connected via USB-C to Displayport
- Windows: one connected via HDMI to Windows Laptop and one via Displayport to Dock

2x Logitech unify Dongle, connected to each Computer (MacBook, Windows Laptop)

I would like to use the inbuilt MX Keys "Easy-Switch"-Buttons, to Change Monitor Input Selection on both Monitors and Switch the MX Master (Mouse)

In the past, I've seen some sort of virtual switches, which detected a keyboard which was switched via a small usb-switch which triggerd a programm on the system which performed monitor switching via displayport/hdmi-connection.

I'd prefer if no installation is required on the windows laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the same, almost done with AutoHotKey, but only with partial success.
You have to send a "VCP control code" to you monitor to change the source.
There are two ways to do it:
01.Use AutoHotKey functions which are using "DllCall"s to do it, see the details here:
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/96884-change-monitor-input-source/

02.Use "ControlMyMonitor" freeware with some attributes in AutoHotKey:

^j::
Run C:\ ...xxx... \controlmymonitor\ControlMyMonitor.exe /SetValue "\.\DISPLAY2\Monitor0" 60 9
return
^k::
Run C:\ ...xxx... \controlmymonitor\ControlMyMonitor.exe /SetValue "\.\DISPLAY2\Monitor0" 60 5
return

--> this script will switch to DisplayPort (code 9) with Ctrl-J and to HDMI1 (code 5) with Ctrl-K.
As the maximum value is 14, you could find your proper values by the good old try and error method after executing ControlMyMonitor (it has a GUI and you need to check VCP 60).

Only 02 worked for me, but it is working reliably, and relative fast.
The bad news is that the the "Easy-Switch" buttons don't have separate identifiers for AutoHotKey (nothing shows in key history, while keyboard hook is on: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys), so other key have to be used for monitor switch, you can't do it with one keypress :(

If any future Logitech software update will allow to assign additional key binds to easy switch buttons, then it could be added to one button.

Answer (score 1):

With similar device configuration (both laptops on windows, one connected through dock, the other through HDMI), following joebacsi's response 02 - "ControlMyMonitor" from Nirsoft one can make a script to switch between laptops based on current state, something like this:

```
ECHO OFF
ControlMyMonitor.exe /GetValue "your device id here" 60
SET LEVEL=%ERRORLEVEL%
IF %LEVEL% == 16 (
  ControlMyMonitor.exe /SetValue "your device id here" 60 17
) ELSE (
  ControlMyMonitor.exe /SetValue "your device id here" 60 16
)
```

where 16, 17 are the proper values for input select (finded into ControlMyMonitor interface)

This script is called from Logitech options (8.36.86)/ mouse tab, gesture button with custom to open file, and should be setup on both laptops.

Answer (score 0):

I don't yet have comment privilege. Have you considered using Remote Desktop/Remote Management over your local network rather than a hardware KVM? A hardware KVM limits you to seeing/interacting with only one host at at time. With Remote Desktop, and large or multiple monitors, you could view both systems concurrently and seamlessly switch between them by simply moving your mouse.

Comment: Windows Device is a company device, RDP is not enabled.

Comment: Re: Windows company device: unless corporate went out of their way to break it, I expect the RDP client still works, and could be used to access the Mac remotely, no?

Comment: @ShawnHughes Mac isn't a remote desktop server. Can only be used as client. But you can connect from Windows to Mac using any VNC viewer. The Mac ScreenSharing service uses VNC protocol.